# Qt Application stuck waiting for a wake event from the system

Tags: c++, qt

I am in a bit of a pickle.

My application has one main window (inherits from `QMainWindow`). The main window is parent to a QTabWidget, which acts as a sort of dialog that shows up when the user clicks a toolbar button on the main window, and hides when its 'Close' button is clicked. In addition, the main window has another toolbar button, which when clicked, calls exec() on a QDialog. While developing the app, I have noticed that once every 40 times or so, clicking one of the two buttons I have mentioned causes an empty widget to appear, but instead of the intended view being drawn, everything freezes. When I click the 'Close' button on the main window, my OS tells me that the application has stopped responding. There is never any way to recover from crashes like this, and I am usually forced to kill the app and restart.

The vexing thing about all this is that I cannot reproduce the crashes at will. They are impossible to predict, and often catch me off-guard.

I used gdb to attach to a frozen instance, and got the following back trace:

```
#0  pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_cond_wait.S:185
#1  0x00007f1ba3bf1b03 in QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, unsigned long) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007f1ba3bea277 in QReadWriteLock::lockForRead() ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#3  0x00007f1b9bf5ee4e in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#4  0x00007f1b9bf61d71 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#5  0x00007f1b9bf64e54 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#6  0x00007f1b904159d6 in dbus_connection_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
#7  0x00007f1b9bf579f5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#8  0x00007f1b9bfa78f5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/plugins/platforms/../../lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
#9  0x00007f1ba3e5a326 in QObject::event(QEvent*) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#10 0x00007f1ba510b8f4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#11 0x00007f1ba510f506 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#12 0x00007f1ba3e25c84 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#13 0x00007f1ba3e28868 in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#14 0x00007f1ba3e80123 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#15 0x00007f1ba283be04 in g_main_context_dispatch () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0x00007f1ba283c048 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#17 0x00007f1ba283c0ec in g_main_context_iteration () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#18 0x00007f1ba3e80554 in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
    () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#19 0x00007f1ba3e23eab in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#20 0x00007f1ba530a2ed in QDialog::exec() () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#21 0x0000000000425fe4 in MainWindow::AddNewDownload() ()
#22 0x00007f1ba3e57e7a in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#23 0x00007f1ba50fee52 in QAction::triggered(bool) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#24 0x00007f1ba5100c77 in QAction::activate(QAction::ActionEvent) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#25 0x00007f1ba520b0b5 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#26 0x00007f1ba520b374 in QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#27 0x00007f1ba52cf89a in QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#28 0x00007f1ba514723c in QWidget::event(QEvent*) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#29 0x00007f1ba52d0730 in QToolButton::event(QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#30 0x00007f1ba510b8f4 in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#31 0x00007f1ba510f071 in QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#32 0x00007f1ba3e25c84 in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#33 0x00007f1ba510df88 in QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool) () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#34 0x00007f1ba5162387 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
#35 0x00007f1ba5164e78 in ?? () from /opt/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

It appears that my app is stuck waiting to be woken up when a certain condition is met. The presence of `dbus` in the back trace suggests that it was trying to talk to another process, which I am guessing is a GUI-related process. I however do not know why the wait condition is met 98% of the time, but fails 2% of the time. When using `strace`, I was able to find that the system call that blocked is:

`futex(0x7f403c00690c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL)`

I am not using `QThreads` or mutexes in my code, so I am guessing this problem is Qt-internal. Does anyone with knowledge of low-level workings of Qt know what is happening?

Comment: Can you post `AddNewDownload` and related source just in case something is wrong there?

Comment: All that slot does is call `exec()` on the  `QDialog`. When the `exec()` method is called, the view is drawn (widgets are created, layouts are set, etc), and the dialog waits for user input. Nothing special is done before the user interacts with the dialog. I could post the code here, but I promise you there is nothing non-standard being done in the `QDialog`'s constructor.